# What is the appropriate way to link all child objects to current?

Tags: c#, parent-child

I'm making a class that will hold a list of child instances which I need to make remember their parent object.

```
class Node
{
    List<Node> childNodes;
    Node ParentNode;
    public Node(List<Node> nodes)
    {
        childNodes = nodes;
        foreach (var node in childNodes)
        {
            node.ParentNode = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Is this a good way or am I missing something?

Comment: Looks entirely reasonable to me. I would change your fields to be properties, but apart from that, your structure is sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I'm assuming this isn't a chicken egg problem. The Parent would be created first and therefore children would be added later. 

public class Node
{
    public List<Node> ChildNodes {get; private set;}
    public Node ParentNode {get; private set;}

    public Node():this(null)
    {
    }

    public Node(Node parentNode)
    {
        ParentNode = parentNode;
        ChildNodes = new List<Node>();
    }

    public void AddChildNode(Node childNode){
       childNode.ParentNode = this;
       ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
    }

}
```